# How to send error messages from express to react/redux

Tags: reactjs, express, redux

I have a MERN app using redux. My actions look like this:

```
export const logIn = (logInData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.logIn(logInData);
    localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(data))
    dispatch({
      type: LOG_IN,
      payload: data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_FLASH_MESSAGE,
      payload: error
    })
  }
}
```

And my server looks like this

```
export const logIn = async (req, res) => {
  const logInParams = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email: logInParams.email });
  if (!user) {
    console.log("USER NOT FOUND");
    res.status(400).json({
      message: "Invalid credentials."
    });
  }

  const passwordMatches = await bcrypt.compare(logInParams.password, user.password);

  if (!passwordMatches) {
    console.log("WRONG PASSWORD")
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Invalid credentials."
    })
  }

    // Sign in user with jwt
    const payload = {
      user: {
        id: user.id
      }
    }

    jwt.sign(payload, config.get('jwtSecret'), (error, token) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log('Successfully logged in');
      return res.status(200).json({
        token: token,
        user: user,
        loggedIn: true
      });
    })
}
```

I'm not able to access my error messages in my actions. I just get error messages like so

```
POST http://localhost:5000/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)
```

And my console.log looks like this:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

How do I access my custom error messages from my server?

Answer (score 1):

try to get the status as `error.status` and custom message as `error.data.message`

Answer (score 1):

your custom error message contain in **error.response.data**
try change this in your action:

```
export const logIn = (logInData) => async (dispatch) => {
try {
   const { data } = await api.logIn(logInData);
   localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(data))
   dispatch({
    type: LOG_IN,
    payload: data
  });
}
 catch (error) {
    dispatch({
     type: ADD_FLASH_MESSAGE,
    payload: **error.response.data**
  })
}
```

}